# In Flutter Editable Widget How to display the save icon on the left side of the table

Tags: flutter, datagrid

In the following flutter widget is there a way to display the "save" icon on the left side of the table. By default it displays on the right extreme. I ant to use it to display an approval list and want the user to click on the icon to approve a given transaction.

```
Editable(
        key: editableKey,
        columns: cols,
        rows: rows,
        zebraStripe: true,
        stripeColor1: Colors.blue,
        stripeColor2: Colors.grey,
        onRowSaved: (value) {
          debugPrint('onRowSaved=$value');
        },
        onSubmitted: (value) {
          debugPrint('onSubmitted=$value');
        },
        borderColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        tdStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        trHeight: 80,
        thStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        thAlignment: TextAlign.center,
        thVertAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        thPaddingBottom: 3,
        showSaveIcon: true,
        saveIconColor: Colors.black,
        saveIcon: Icons.approval_sharp,
        showCreateButton: true,
        tdAlignment: TextAlign.left,
        tdEditableMaxLines: 100, // don't limit and allow data to wrap
        tdPaddingTop: 0,
        tdPaddingBottom: 14,
        tdPaddingLeft: 10,
        tdPaddingRight: 8,
        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0))),
      )
```

*** Edit ****

Here is the current UI Image. The right-most images are the Save icons. I want these to be displayed on the left side of the table.

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the current ui image ?

Comment: @Dhrumil Shah
I have added the image

Comment: Unfortunately Editable will not let us change the position of save button, by default it renders remove and save button at the end of the row. check this link, it is statically positioned in the row    https://github.com/godilite/editable/blob/1ae962e6a7a963a44b0cc64bfa6da1c630b0f3de/lib/editable.dart#L405

Comment: Ahhh! So no luck. Will try other widgets instead. Thanks